# call a method in a specific times in every seconds

Tags: javascript, methods, setinterval, clock, clearinterval

I want to call a method 5 times in every  one second. for example I have a methodA which i want to execute this method in 5 times in every 1 second. so how can i do it.

```
methodA(){
console.log("called")
}

timePeriod(){

setimeout....

}
```

Comment: [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: Do you mean once every 0.2 seconds or that after each second you call it 5 times "instantaneously" (on the same tick)

Comment: @vjtechno ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @vjtechno ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let timePeriod = 1000  // 1000 ms
function methodA(){
  console.log("called")
}

setInterval(methodA, timePeriod)
```

notice here that we pass the function as an argument without `()` which in other words we're referencing the function. Note that if you pass the function name along with `()` it means you're calling it independently

Also, keep in mind that `setInterval` works a little bit different than you might think as it's a **macro task asynchronous function in the event loop**. if you don't know about the event loop simply all you need to know that `setInterval`  doesn't actually call the function unless the rest of you script gets fired + the time period you specify

setInterval = the time needed to fire the rest of the script + the time period you specify

and what you can do to test this is:

```js
const  tick  =  Date.now(),  timeLog  =  (val='---')  =>  console.log(`${val}  \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() -  tick} ms`)

setInterval(_ => timeLog('smth from setInterval'), 1000)

for(let i=1;i<1000000000;i++){
  // this loop will run for 1B times so that we get a clear time delay
}
timeLog('smth from normal console.log')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ***setInterval()***

```js
const test = setInterval(() => console.log("Hello method"),1000);
setTimeout( () => clearInterval(test), 5000);
```

Hope it is what you need!

Answer (score 1):

```
const Comp= () => {
const methodA=()=>{
//   statement here
}
  useEffect(()=>{
    let a = setInterval(methodA,1000/5)
    return(()=>{
      clearInterval(a)
    },[])
  })
  return(<></>)
}
```

Try to use interval inside useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1):

One could control both, [the interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) itself and also the condition for terminating the running interval, by writing a utility/helper function which enables not only *clocked functions* but also *clocked methods*.

```js
function clocked(interval, isTerminate, proceed, target) {
  let count = 0;
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {

    proceed.call(target ?? null);

    if (isTerminate(++count)) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, interval);
}

const obj = {
  text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
  log() {
    console.log(this.text);
  },
};
function doTerminateWhen(counter) {
  return counter >= 5;
}

setTimeout(() => { console.log('1.001 seconds passed'); }, 1001);

clocked(200, doTerminateWhen, obj.log, obj);

setTimeout(() => { console.log('1 second passed'); }, 1000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**setInterval** is being used her to call the **methodA** function at each once second and **modCall** function has a for loop to iterate and call the **setInterval** the number of times specified in its **paramter**

```js
function methodA(i){
 console.log('call '+i)
}

function modCall(len){
for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
setInterval(()=>methodA(i),1000)
}
}

modCall(5) //5 is number of time you want to call the methodA
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).